# Excluding specific email addresses from a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Our database has a lot of fake emails in there which we would prefer not to send to. I've begun to enter these, as well as other preventative addresses, into a data extension which I want to use to use to exclude these contacts in journey builder sends.

As a lot of this is preventative the data extension just contains email addresses.

I already have a Domain Exclusion extension up and running but this only works to filter out addresses on a domain level. I want to exclude the likes of fake@gmail.com and xxx@gmail.com etc.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Could you leverage the filters in the Entry Source in the journey builder to filter out these email addresses?

Comment: I started doing that but it is not looking like it will be scalable for the number email addresses I want to exclude and the number of journeys that will be put in place. A table would be easier as more email addresses can be added to it incrementally.

Comment: you could also import your exclusion data extension as an auto suppression list as required. You then wouldn't need to worry about excluding them at the journey level but rather at the sender profile or classification level.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use auto suppression list to suppress these kinds of email addresses so that they get suppressed without needing to manage in journeys. It will also mean these email addresses will be suppressed for all kind of sends. Sender profiles can be used to suppress specific sends to that sender profiles.

Comment: I would say most address like this would be excluded through link detective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the emails you want to exclude in a data extension, you can use an [Exclusion Script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320456&language=en_US&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&mode=1) in the Journey Builder send.

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Exclusion_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME","EMAIL_ADDR_FIELD_NAME", EMAILADDR))>0
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question.